# PHP redirect based on multiple (more than 5) referring domains

Tags: php, redirect, header, referrer

Currently we have 25+ domains forwarding to one single www.mydomain.com. What I need to do using PHP is forward traffic once again to www.mydomain.com/#.html based on the referring domain. so...

www.mydomain1.com -> www.mydomain.com -> www.mydomain.com/1

I've been able to accomplish this for 2 using an If/ElseIf/Else statement, but to take it further, I believe I will need to use a Switch/Case routine, but I'm not sure of the best way to do it.

Answer (score 5):

```
$referrers = array(
  "domain.com" => "somepage.html",
  "domain2.com" => "somepage2.html"
);

$referrer = //get domain coming from

if( !empty( $referrers[$referrer] ) ) {
    // redirect to $referrers[$referrer];
}
```

Comment: 1° It's "HTTP_REFERER" (they messed up the spelling) and 2° I suspect he means a DNS forward, not a redirect, so $_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'] should be used instead.

Comment: removed referrer altogether...I wasn't really venturing to guess what he was doing for the redirect...I was just showing an alternative to switch()s and if/else.  With this approach, using an array, you can hard-code the array or use a DB to load the array and leave your code alone rather than having to rewrite it when more options are needed.